# How to tell which file was created first?

Tags: linux, pid, ctime

On a Linux system (the one in front of me is an Ubuntu 10.04, but that shouldn't matter), how can I tell which of two files created within the same second was created first? The process I control creates neither itself; in all other respects the ctime would, I think, do the trick, but the 1 second resolution is a problem.

For background, I'm trying to reliably determine whether a potentially stale pidfile refers to the current process with that pid. If there's a better way to do that, I'm all ears.

Comment: this is highly filesystem dependant. For example, `ext3` only has one second resolution (see [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3)).

Comment: As long as I can do a comparison between ext3 and /proc, I'm ok.

Comment: If ext3 tells you you file's ctime is `14:03:30` and your proc file is `14:03:30'050`, how can you decide which one was created before?

Comment: That's the question; thus "if there's a better way..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, on modern Unices with modern filesystems, the file modification time is stored in a timespec. Details:

[The standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html) says `stat` looks like this WRT times:

```
struct timespec st_atim Last data access timestamp. 
struct timespec st_mtim Last data modification timestamp. 
struct timespec st_ctim Last file status change timestamp.
```

And a [`timespec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html)

```
time_t  tv_sec    seconds
long    tv_nsec   nanoseconds
```

So, doing a stat on my Linux 2.6.39:

```
Access: 2011-07-14 15:38:20.016666721 +0300
Modify: 2011-06-10 03:06:12.000000000 +0300
Change: 2011-06-17 11:01:35.416667110 +0300
```

In conclusion, I think you've got enough precision there if the hardware is supplying it.

Comment: Hm. In which case, the precision is getting lost somewhere in the stack between me (sat in a Ruby VM) and the hardware. I'll have to dig further, I think.

Comment: Check whether you can run the `stat(2)` system call. Chances are (because of the VM), you can't. Try JNA (needs no compiler, unlike JNI) or an independent executable that you can invoke via `ProcessBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ls -rt` to sort the files by time on the hope that the file header has more precision than the default list time format displays. But if the file system doesn't have the information, there is no way to do this.

Other options? You could add an ID to the file and always increment it but as soon as you try to load this ID from the file system (when you create a new process), you'll run into problems with locking.

So how can you make sure the PID file is not stale? Answer: Use [the `daemon` script](http://www.libslack.org/daemon/). It runs a process in the background and makes sure the PID file gets deleted as soon as the process exits.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is that I'm effectively *writing* a daemon script.

Comment: Ah, the pure bliss of reinventing the wheel. My suggestion: Just write a normal process and use the daemon script to turn it into a daemon.